# Duck Duck Go SEO

Tags: seo, search-engines

The search engine [duck duck go](http://duckduckgo.com/) has generated some interest, and there are a few people who use it. I was wondering if if would be worth while to optimize my site to rank better on duck duck go, and if it is worthwhile, if there are any tips for how to rank better on their site.

Comment: Interest from who? Not from anyone I know.

Comment: Offtopic: I like how scrolling down at duckduckgo populates more search results without having to go to a second page. Google should do that. Takes away the irrelevancy of the second page.

Comment: I would suggest that Blekko has gained more interest than DDG...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't even give that search engine a thought. Until they reach a critical mass and can potentially deliver real traffic oit's not worth doing anything special for them.

Anyway, if your site is done properly you will be optimized for every search engine. There shouldn't be a need to do anything for any one search engine.

Comment: I should have been clearer: I was wondering if there were any tips that would help me rank better on duck duck go. However, that's irrelevant, because as you said they don't have enough users to make it worthwhile.

Comment: Whomever downvoted care to explain why?

Comment: Looks like it's worth revisiting this answer. Critical mass achieved : )  DuckDuckGo is now at approx 10 million daily queries. See [How DuckDuckGo Rode A Wave Of Post-Snowden Anxiety To Massive Growth](http://www.fastcompany.com/3046943/how-duckduckgo-rode-a-wave-of-post-snowden-anxiety-to-massive-growth).  They aren't anywhere near Google-scale, but it's waaaay up on their 2011 numbers.  All that said, John's point about a properly done site working for every search engine is still valid.